# Issue with Python function

Tags: python, function

I am developing some functions, but this one doesn't work and i can't see any reason why:

```
def f():
    t = raw_input('Enter a number and we will send an inormation: ')

    if t % 2 == 0:
            print t
            print 'it is an even number'

    elif t % 2 > 0:
            print t
            print 'it is an odd number'

    else t != type(int):
            print 'is this a number ?'
```

it should show the number and the message but when I start the program it says:

```
def f():
    t = raw_input('Enter a number and we will send an inormation: ')

    if t % 2 == 0:
            print t
            print 'it is an even number'

    elif t % 2 > 0:
            print t
            print 'it is an odd number'

    else t != type(int):
            print 'is this a number ?'

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The text (^) doesn't show, but the t from the else is highlighted and when erase the else part of the program, the error repeats in the elif BUT when I erase else and elif ( just keep the if) it works. do you know why???

Comment: well, `else t != type(int):` is invalid syntax. Else cannot have another "if" clause after it. Where exactly have you seen this type of construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` part of an `if` statement does not have a condition following it. An `else` catches all executions that were not caught by preceding `if` and `elif` lines.

So either remove the `t != type(int)` condition after the `else` or change the `else` to an `elif`.

Comment: thanks! it worked, but I'll continue testing just in case of other error. :)

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. But I appreciate the thanks!

Comment: i know, but i need to have 15 something ponits and i think that I just have one :(